# Navigation links not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I just uploaded my [website](http://www.svdpplymouth.org). It's incomplete, but I just needed to check if the links were working. And it seems that they are not working. I can't figure out why my top navigation links "Home, About, Vinnies, Outreach, Crossroads, Contact" are not working.

FYI - the uploaded and working pages are "Home, About, Outreach, Contact". They are working and if I type their URL in a browser, the page shows up. For example: http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html. But I cannot link nav links from the index page. The URL for the specific child page shows up in the status bar (browser) down below.

Need help.

```css
/*

Compass Template
    
http://www.templatemo.com/tm-454-compass


http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)

*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Basic Styling 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font: 13px/23px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #777777;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
}
.hr {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
height: 1px;
margin: 10px 0;
width: 40%;
text-align:left; margin: 0 auto;
}


.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons, .main-header .menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#homecontent,  #about, #contact, #vinnies, #outreach, #crossroads {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Header Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000
}

:target:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:60px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin:-60px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}

#body-header {
  margin-top: 170px;
  
}

.top-header {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 1000
}

.top-header .left-header span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 20px 0 0;
}
.top-header .left-header span i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a {
  color: white;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #191970;
}
.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-header .logo {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.main-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-header .logo h1 a {
  color: #444444;
}
.main-header .menu {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a.current {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
}
.main-header-shrink {
  padding: 10px 0;
  top: 0;
}
#body-header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: #b7dd33;
}

#body-header  .nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#body-header .nav ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

#body-header .nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #191970;
  color: #ffffff;
}




.responsive-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
.responsive-menu .toggle-menu {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1601c;
  margin: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a.current {
  background-color: #444444;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Basic Layout Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.title-section {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.title-section h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.title-section span {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #191970;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.widget-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.mainBtn {
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.mainBtn:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
}
.tweet_txt {
 border-left:2px solid #ffffff; 
 min-height:160px;
}
.about-tweets {
    background-color: #8996a0;
    min-height:150px;
    font-family:  'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.tweet_user {
 color: #FFFF33; 
 font-size: 14px;
 float: right;
}

.tweet_txt-sm {
 border-left:2px solid #ffffff; 
 min-height:120px;
}
.about-tweets-sm {
    background-color: #8996a0;
    min-height:150px;
    font-family:  'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.tweet_user-sm {
 color: #FFFF33; 
 font-size: 14px;
 float: right;
}





/*------------------------------------------------------
 Specialty Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
   

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Home Content Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header .homecontent-description {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;

}
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header i {
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 24px; 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li a {
  color: #191970;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: solid; 1px; #191970;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: #9fff80;
  color: #191970;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 About Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/

#about .about-image {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
#about .progess-bars li .progress-bar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #191970;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#about .our-team {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #191970;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content span {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------
 Outreach Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/

#outreach .outreachcontent h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #e3722e;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------
 Crossroads Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/



/*------------------------------------------------------
 Contact Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/

#contact .contact-form .full-row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#contact .contact-form input, #contact .contact-form textarea {
  outline: 0;
  display: block; 
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #777777;
}
#contact .contact-form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#contact .contact-form input.mainBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
}
#contact .map-holder {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
#contact .contact-info {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#contact .contact-info span {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#contact .contact-info span i {
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.flexslider {
  margin-top: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
  color: #444444;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.flex-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
}
.flex-caption h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.flex-caption p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.flex-caption span {
  background: url(../images/slider-dec.png) no-repeat;
  width: 60px;
  height: 9px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------
 Footer Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
.site-footer p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.site-footer a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.site-footer .go-top {
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.site-footer .go-top i {
  display: block;
}

/********************************
IPAD LANDSCAPE (1024x768)
********************************/
/********************************
IPAD PORTRAIT (768x1024)
********************************/



@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

  .main-header {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .service-item, .team-member {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .our-skills {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .flex-caption {
    top: 20%;
  }
  .flex-caption h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .flex-caption p {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .left-header, .right-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/********************************
IPHONE 4-4S-5 LANDSCAPE (568x320)
********************************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .flex-caption {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .contact-form {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

  .main-header {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .responsive-menu .menu {
    top: 32px;
  }
}


/********************************
IPHONE 4-4S-5 PORTRAIT (320x568)
********************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Society of St. Vincent de Paul Plymouth WI - Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="templatemo">
    <!-- 
    Compass Template
    http://www.templatemo.com/tm-454-compass
    -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- CSS Bootstrap & Custom -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-misc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-main.css">
        
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
 <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
            <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="header">
        <div class="site-header">
            <div class="top-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="left-header">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>920-892-4913</span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@svdpplymouth.org">info@svdpplymouth.org</a></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>M-F 9AM-7PM SAT 9AM-5PM</span>
                            </div> <!-- /.left-header -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="right-header text-right">
                                <ul class="social-icons">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/?q=#/svdpplymouth" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/svdpply/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/svdpplymouth/" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/svdp_ply" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- /.left-header -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                    </div> <!-- /.row -->
                </div> <!-- /.container -->
            </div> <!-- /.top-header -->
            <div class="main-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <h1><img src="images/SVDPlogotitle.png"></h1>
                            </div> <!-- /.logo -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="menu text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html">Vinnies</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
         <ul>
          <li class="fa fa-hand-o-right"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html#volunteer" style="font-size:12px;">Volunteer</a></li>
          <li class="fa fa-heart-o"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/donations.html" style="font-size:12px;">Donations</a></li>
          <li class="fa fa-check-square-o"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html#outreachapps" style="font-size:12px;">Applications-Forms</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div> <!-- /.menu -->
      </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
     </div> <!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="responsive-menu text-right visible-xs visible-sm">
                        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu fa fa-bars"></a>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html">Vinnies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /.menu -->
                    </div> <!-- /.responsive-menu -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
            </div> <!-- /.header -->
        </div> <!-- /.site-header -->
    </div> <!-- /#home -->

    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html"><img src="images/hearthand.jpg" alt="Hands Holding Heart"></a>
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h2>Serve People in Need</h2>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>As Vincentians, we help members of the community, while growing spiritually and building friendships.<br>We help you help others! Love in Action! Live Your Faith!</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html"><img src="images/truck1.jpg" alt="Vincentians"></a>
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h2>Community Assistance</h2>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>Vincentians see the face of Christ in those we serve.<br>Offering prayer, financial assistance, counseling, mentoring, and in-store assistance.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
   <li>
                <a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html"><img src="images/store2.jpg" alt="Vinnies"></a>
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h2>Shop @ Vinnies</h2>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>Support your community and save money shopping with us!<br>Program revenue is generated through purchases at our store.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
   <li>
                <a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/donations.html"><img src="images/donate.jpg" alt="Donations"></a>
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h2>Donations & Purchases</h2>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>Your gifts, donations and store patronage provide vital financial support to families in need<br>Your monies bring support to these assistance programs.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
  </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Society of St. Vincent de Paul Plymouth WI</p>
     <p>2225 Eastern Ave Plymouth, WI 53073</p>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="go-top">
                        <a href="#" id="go-top">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                            Back to Top
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div> <!-- /.site-footer -->

    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
     scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.758468,100.567481)
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        function loadScript() {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
              'callback=initialize';
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a javascript error on page - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null. This may be preventing other scripts from firing.... If your site has some sort of click tracker running it may be breaking because of that offsetWidth error.

Comment: Just to add to the previous comment form @AaronLavers. In your question you did not mention what have you tried to solve the problem. Second, if you have a problem you should only include the [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not the whole page. By the way, are you sure you have uploaded all the ``html`` pages to your hosting? It seems that only ``index.html`` is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the working navigation menu [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONQpyv). There is nothing wrong with the links though. But, there might be the problem with second css `templatemo-misc.css`.

This is the minimal working sample:

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-misc.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templatemo-main.css">
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-C6CB9UYIS9UJeqinPHWTHVqh/E1uhG5Twh+Y5qFQmYg="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1><img src="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/images/SVDPlogotitle.png"></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                <div class="menu text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html">Vinnies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="fa fa-hand-o-right"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html#volunteer" style="font-size:12px;">Volunteer</a></li>
                        <li class="fa fa-heart-o"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/donations.html" style="font-size:12px;">Donations</a></li>
                        <li class="fa fa-check-square-o"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html#outreachapps" style="font-size:12px;">Applications-Forms</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive-menu text-right visible-xs visible-sm">
            <a href="#" class="toggle-menu fa fa-bars"></a>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html">Vinnies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<body>
```

UPDATE: the reason why external links were not working it is because it is specified in `custom.js` find this `js` file and comment out the following lines:

```
$('.menu').singlePageNav(
        {filter: ':not(.external)'}
    );
```

Every link should work then.

Comment: Thank you for showing me minimal working sample. I will make sure I follow that guideline from now on. Can I upload my templatemo-misc.css file to show you? Do I upload it in a comment? I used your working navigating menu from above on my index page, but I get a gap between my header and flexslider now. My entire header is fixed. Now sure what to do.

Comment: The other three working .html pages I am using, right now, are uploaded to my host. I can open them, specifically, in browser. www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html, www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html, www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html and they are viewable.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but I'm using the following javascript on the child pages (outreach.html, about.html, contact.html) because of my fixed header. I am using this because when I link to anchors on child pages, portion of body-header would slide under the fixed header area:
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
 <script>
    var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -140) };
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
    function load() { if (window.location.hash) shiftWindow(); } </script>

Comment: I'm debating just taking out the fixed header because it seems like more of a problem than anything.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! That worked. I believe I accepted your answer correctly by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. And thank you for your other helpful suggestions too.